# S3: reading an object in the reverse order?

Tags: amazon-s3

Let's say we have an object stored on S3. Is it possible to read it in the reverse byte order? Does S3 API provide with such a functionality?

I need to read a huge file in the reverse order because it was written in the reverse order by someone else. I don't want to do that in memory, I don't want to save the file on my local disk and then read it again.

Comment: There might be some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56139995/102937).  It describes breaking a file into smaller chunks using an EC2 instance.  You could then read the chunks in reverse order.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the idea of reading chunks in reverse order and then reverse them in memory is a good one. I was thinking about the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Andremoniy, if you're looking for a solution programmatically using Java I can try helping you out with that, I have a working solution which is fast and doesn't require much memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

You can download the entire file or a range request of [any single contiguous range](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/GettingObjectsUsingAPIs.html) of bytes, but this always happens in the same order that they were uploaded.